# Defining many to many relationship

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm struggling defining the following relationships:

1. A User can have MANY posts.
2. A User can belong as collaborator to MANY posts.
3. A post has ONE owner.
4. A post can have MANY users (i.e. collaborators). (The owner can add them later on)

```
    Class User(){
       public Guid Id{ get; set; }
    }

    class UserPost(){
       public Guid UserId { get; set; }
       public User User { get; set; }

       public Guid PostId { get; set; }
       public { get; set; }
    }

    class Post(){
       public IList<UserPost> UserPost{ get; set; }
       public Guid AuthorId { get; set; }
       public User Author { get; set; }
       public string Title { get; set; }
    }
```

Is my code a correct representation of the relationship?

Comment: I think that point #3 and #4 might be the same as #1 and #2. Am I right?

Comment: Hey Alex, welcome to SO. Where's the representation of the Collaborators? Also, if i.e. the Post has a Guid AuthorId object (a foreign key) it doesn't have to also have a User object (ownership/dependency), am I right to understand that the AuthorId will be the same as Author.Id? And finally, what's the public { get; set; } object? This is not syntactically correct.

Comment: Hi and thank you. :) A Collaborator is a User. I'm following a tutorial and there they also create the Author property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of these needs to be a separate relationship. Which means you need something like:

```
public class User
{
    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PostCollaborator> CollaboratingPosts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public User Owner { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PostCollaborator> Collaborators { get; set; }
}

public class PostCollaborator
{
    public Post Post { get; set; }
    public User Collaborator { get; set; }
}
```

In other words, the post owner relationship is actually a one-to-many. A user can have many owned posts, but each post has only one owner. The post collaborator relationship is a many-to-many, which then requires a join entity `PostCollaborator`.